# How to make optional datetime parameter in Flutter with null safety

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new to Flutter development and trying to learn.
I want to create a model with a constructor, one of which contains a field of type `DateTime` which is optional.

I tried by making it like this:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Customer extends Equatable {
  final int indexs;
  final DateTime apply_date;

  Customer({
    required this.indexs,
    this.apply_date,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

But an error message appears like this

> The parameter 'apply_date' can't have a value of 'null' because of its
> type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. Try adding either an
> explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

I've tried to learn from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560461/the-parameter-cant-have-a-value-of-null-because-of-its-type-in-dart) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444474/make-function-parameter-optional-in-custom-widget-flutter) reference, and what I understand there are 3 ways:

1. Include `required` modifiers
2. Set initial value
3. Nulllabel parameter / Fill it with (?) => I don't understand this

So how to do this properly?
I don't want to make this field `required`, because it's optional.
I also don't know what to fill if I want to fill it with an initialvalue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the attribute nullable is the same as making it an optional attribute.

You can do that by adding `?` behind the attribute's type.

```
class Customer extends Equatable {
  final int indexs;
  final DateTime? apply_date;

  Customer({
    required this.indexs,
    this.apply_date,
  });

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

Comment: Ahh, it's that easy.. Thank you!